# What is the interpretation of a statistical CL contour *in the case* where the central observed measurement does not belong to the interior?

Tags: neutrinos, statistics

What is the interpretation of a statistical Confidence Level contour *in the case* where the central observed measurement does not belong to the interior of the contour ? (you may see below that this case really does exist)

Introduction : we have typically a measurement made of two parameters of interests (POI) : POI1 and POI2 : we could represent the central value of a measurement (with a likelihood fit) in the phase space POI1 vs POI2. In addition to that, since the measurements have some uncertainties, we could construct a confidence level contour at a given percentage value or expressed in a given number of sigma of a gaussian. For example a 90 % CL contour shows the contour for which 90 % of the measurements are inside the contour.

Fine so far. Now the problem :

My problem is the special case where the central measurement value would not belong to the interior of the contour.

Take this example in neutrino experiments : they make a simultaneous fit of two parameters: $\sin^2{\theta_{23}}$ and $\delta_{CP}$, together with the hypothetic scenario "NH" (Normal Hierarchy) scenario, or the "IH" (Invert Hierarchy) scenario. I believe (but I'm not completely sure) that the most probable scenario (NH or IH) is "stated" by the fit, as a kind of third variable (with two possible values : NH or IH).

Nature (measurement) favors the NH case.
The point is that there is also a confidence level contour for the case (IH) which is not the favored scenario : so it represents a contour without the central value inside.

-> What is the *interpretation of this contour* without the measurement inside ?

Is it just a non connex contour ?

See for example Figure 3 of :
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.04907.pdf
[image]

(the central value is shown with a black marker)

Comment: Cross Validated SE might be more suitable for this question.

Comment: ok, I create it to the other place. Thank you